# Application CTRL-C signal works only once

Tags: c#, console

I am having a rather weird problem I've been unable to Google out.

Working on some barely-sensical school demo program, I'm required to have a worker loop go about it's business, until it's interrupted by a CTRL-C signal, which then runs some other function. When that's done, the program resumes it's previous worker loop where it left off.

All that works beautifully, the new keypress event is done like this:

```
Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false;
Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(interrupt);
```

When CTRL-C is pressed, the "interrupt" method is correctly called and executed... once.

When it's through, I appear to be completely unable to call it again via interrupt signal. Any subsequent CTRL-C keypress is completely ignored.

The "interrupt" method ends with .Join to merge with it's parent thread, since the event handlers are ran on seperate threads for some reason.

What is preventing me from calling the interrupt method as many times as I want?

Comment: Post some of your threading code.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Join` doesn't "merge" threads. It blocks the current thread until the other thread is finished. As you are joining on the main thread, this will never happen until the program exits.

Just remove that call completely.

Comment: Hm, in that case, how would I go from returning from the interrupt thread, to the main thread once it's done? Use what instead of .Join? Without it, the program simply exists when it reaches the end of the interrupt method (where the .Join used to be). I need it to return to the caller thread instead of exiting.

Comment: @user2245664: The problem is not that your code doesn't return to the main thread. That's the whole point of threads: They run in parallel. Most likely, you forgot to set `args.Cancel` to `true` as per Jon's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting the [`Cancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.consolecanceleventargs.cancel.aspx) property to `true` appropriately? This works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false;
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, args) => {
            // We want to keep going...
            args.Cancel = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Handler called");
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Go for it!");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear what your threading looks like - that could well be another aspect which is incorrect, as per Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Console.TreatControlCAsInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput.aspx) looks like it should not be set to false:

> true if Ctrl+C is treated as ordinary input; otherwise, false.